# How many names - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Oh the different names I am called,
If I end badly, you may be mauled.
Head, shoulders, knees, and toes,
Sometimes there are subtle blows.

One plus one equals one and a half
The clock's going, now don't laugh
It is a fierce battle often in rage,
That takes place on a green stage.

Most of the world says I'm pretty great,
From buenos días to G'day mate!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it

> Soccer/football?

Oh the different names I am called,

> See above

If I end badly, you may be mauled.

> Riots during/after games

Head, shoulders, knees, and toes,

> What you use to hit the ball

Sometimes there are subtle blows.

> Slide tackles, running into each other, heads into chests (less subtle)

One plus one equals one and a half

> The two periods = 1 hour 30 min

The clock's going, now don't laugh

> Clock always runs

It is a fierce battle often in rage,

> It's a sport, passions happen

That takes place on a green stage.

> Grass field

Most of the world says I'm pretty great,

> World Cup!

From buenos días to G'day mate!

> World Cup!

Comment: Well that was fast! Nicely done! Now I need to come up with another one.

Comment: The green stage comment is where I really honed in on an idea.

Comment: I almost just made it a flat stage. Should have stuck with that.